# Are "constructor statement" and "declaration statement" correct names to describe these statements?

Tags: java, constructor, expression, variable-declaration, jls

I am confused about the following Java statements:

```
ArtClass artClass0 = new ArtClass();
int int3 = 73;
boolean boolean0 = artClass0.foo(int3);
```

Is the first statement called `constructor statement`? For the second and third statements, are both of them considered as `declaration statements`? If so, how can I distinguish between them? I need to distinguish between the two statements as I am writing that in my thesis.

Comment: There is no such thing as a constructor statement. All three statements are declaration statements, as they all declare a variable. It so happens they also all initialize the variable they declare with an initial value.

Comment: All three lines are declarations since you introduce the variable with it's type. All three lines are also assignments, since you assign a value to the respective variable. Lines 2, 1 and 3 only differ by the right hand side: `73` is a constant value known at compile time, `new ArtClass()` (a call to the constructor of ArtClass`) and `artClass0.foo(int3)` are evaluated at runtime.

Comment: I can't remember I have heard about anything like `constructor statement`. I am not sure from where have you found that term.

Comment: A constructor is a specific type of method used for instantiation of an object, i.e. `public ArtClass(String className) { ... }`. I don't know what a *constructor statement* is, but it may be a reference to the constructor itself?

Answer (score 3):

They all are [Local Variable Declaration Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4), which simply can be written as

```
VariableDeclaratorId [= VariableInitializer]
```

I'll give you the exact terminology used in [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/index.html) to name [nonterminals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.1). Any nonterminals mentioned below can be found in the specification.

```
ArtClass artClass0 = new ArtClass();
```

is

```
[UnannReferenceType [UnannClassOrInterfaceType]] Identifier
     = [Primary [PrimaryNoNewArray [ClassInstanceCreationExpression]]];
```

---

```
 int int3 = 73;
```

is

```
[UnannPrimitiveType [NumericType [IntegralType [int]]]] Identifier
    = [Literal [IntegerLiteral [DecimalIntegerLiteral]]];
```

---

```
boolean boolean0 = artClass0.foo(int3);
```

is

```
[UnannPrimitiveType [boolean]] Identifier
    = [Primary [PrimaryNoNewArray [MethodInvocation]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is the first statement called constructor statement?

No, there is no such term **"constructor statement"** in Java, at least not officially. Check the [Java Tutorial at Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html), there is only 3 types of statements:

1. Expression Statement
2. Declaration Statement
3. Control Flow Statement

Expression Statement may include following expressions concluded by `;`:

- Assignment expressions *[e.g. a = 5]*
- Any use of ++ or -- *[e.g. a++]*
- Method invocations *[e.g. foo(a)]*
- Object creation expressions *[e.g. MyClass myClass = new MyClass()]*

And when we declare a variable, that is called Declaration Statement.

In your example in the question,

```
ArtClass artClass0 = new ArtClass();
```

The above one is a object creation expression, hence we call it expression statement. On the other hand,

```
int int3 = 73;
boolean boolean0 = artClass0.foo(int3);
```

In both cases, we are declaring the variables. So, they are declaration statement.

However, be careful about below statements:

```
int int3; // Declaration Statement
int3 = 73; // Expression Statement
boolean boolean0; // Declaration Statement
boolean0 = artClass0.foo(int3); // Expression Statement
```

Comment: Thanks but in your opinion, how can I distinguish between the last two statements when I write about them?

Comment: Where is your confusion about last two statements?

Comment: I would think that `new MyClass()` alone is an object creation expression.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Check the oracle link I have provided in my answer. They have example there.

Comment: I saw that, I just don't agree with it.The terminology used in that tutorial doesn't match the terminology from the Java Language Specification where `new Something()` is called a _class instance creation expression_, while `type name = expression` (eg `Something something = new Something()`) is called a _VariableDeclarator_, so I wouldn't take the terms from that tutorial as the official terminology.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, your explanation - that's true. But this is confusing as the tutorial is also by Oracle. I'm pretty sure they wouldn't write anything without considering the official doc. So, I will have to do more research on this topic for conclusion at this matter, at least to find out the references they have used to write that tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The official terminology of the Java language is defined in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/index.html).

All three statements are [Local Variable Declaration Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4), but their variable initializers use different expressions. Specifically:

- `new ArtClass()` is a [class instance creation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)
- `73` is a [literal expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1)
- `artClass0.foo(int3)` is a [method invocation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

If you wish to distinguish according to the type of variable being declared, you might say that the first declares a variable of [reference type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3), while the others declare variables of [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) (or more specifically an "int" or "boolean variable").